# Python - return back to class?

Tags: python

```
class Begin:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, year):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.year = year
    print('Welcome to the interactive decision matrix! ')
    firstname = input(f'Please begin with entering your first name: ')
    lastname = input('Last name ?')
    year = input('Year? ')

    make_sure = input(f'Just to make sure, your name is {firstname} {lastname}, and the year is {year} ? (Y/N)')
    if make_sure.lower() == 'y':
        pass
    else:

        **Begin(__init__())  #Doesn't recognises the class? How do I go back?**


print('Hello')
```

Comment: You're code is bad indentd please correct it

Comment: Why doing those things in `__init__()` or in the class?  I would do them outside the class.

Comment: It's unclear whether the indentation of your code in the question is correct, it's unclear what you want to do and it's unclear what you want to know. There's only one thing that is clear: you need to learn more about OOP.

Comment: @Matthias Will do. Sorry for the noob question. I just want to restart the code if the answer is 'n' or ''N''

Comment: @Bishop1701 This might be something you want to read [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Begin:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, year):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.year = year


def main():
    print('Welcome to the interactive decision matrix! ')

    while True:
        firstname = input(f'Please begin with entering your first name: ')
        lastname = input('Last name ?')
        year = input('Year? ')

        make_sure = input(f'Just to make sure, your name is {firstname} {lastname}, and the year is {year} ? (Y/N)')
        if make_sure.lower() == 'y':
            begin = Begin(firstname, lastname, year)
            break

    print(f'Hello, your name is {begin.firstname} {begin.lastname}, and the year is {begin.year}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```